# How to change user within PostgreSQL?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I was following the tutorial linked below to install PostgreSQL with python3 on Ubuntu:
https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/postgresql-python-3-psycopg2-ubuntu-1604.html

Right after this step:

```
$ createuser matt -P --interactive
```

Where we create a user account within the "postgres" base user provided by PostgreSQL.

I then close the terminal to come back to the tutorial afterward.
I couldn't find how to switch back to the user previously created and finally went around it with:

```
ALTER DATABASE name_db OWNER TO name_new_user.
```

But how am I supposed to switch from 'postgres' default user to another user created previously in PostgreSQL?

Comment: What do you mean with "within the postgres base user"? You can't create one user "within" another. Did you mean "within the postgres _database_"? But to "switch" the user, you need to create a new connection logging in with that new user

Comment: Are you looking for the `-U matt` option of psql?

Answer (score 0):

If you're already logged in to PostgreSQL, you can change users with the `set role` command, for example, to switch to "matt":

`set role matt;`

If you're not already logged in to PostgreSQL, and are using `psql`, there are a few ways:

```
$ psql -U matt
```

of if you want to usually log in as matt:

```
$ echo 'PGUSER=matt' >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
$ psql
```

where `.profile` is where you store OS environment variables